"Subtotals ignored" in LookML dashboard preventing expanding/collapsing records
I have a user-defined Looker dashboard which includes a table visualization with a product_category and product column. Subtotals in this visualization are enabled in order to allow users to expand the product_category rows in the first column in order to reveal the underlying products in the second products column.



product_category
product




> product_category_1



> product_category_2







product_category
product




^ product_category_1




product_1



product_2



product_3


> product_category_2




When I attempt to convert this dashboard into a LookML dashboard however, I receive the following error which disables the expand/collapse functionality even though the subtotals button is still enabled:
Requested subtotal on field view_name.product_category but it was not in the grouping fields. Subtotal ignored.
Is there a parameter that I need to include in my LookML to enable the subtotals in this visualization?
I have already tried recreating the visualization by selecting "Get LookML" with the subtotals selected, but I still get the same error.
